# C++ 14: How to use variadic template to create an array of values 1-100

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, list-comprehension, variadic

I wish to get an array of values `int buf[]={1...100}`. I wish this array can be constructed at compile time, using variadic template. This is like list comprehension of Python/Haskell, etc.

But can c++11/14 template do it, and how?
Thanks

Comment: Don't see a way to do it in the global namespace, but this array could be declared as a static member of a helper class. Still, if your goal is really to simply initialize an `int` array, just write a script to robo-generate the source code, instead of messing around with templates. And if your goal is to do your homework assignment, the whole reason for it would be for you to figure it out by yourself, instead of getting someone else on stackoverflow.com to do your homework assignment for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are really set on making this at compile-time. You could do it with an `integer_sequence` and a `std::array`

```
#include <utility>
#include <array>

template <int... Is> // when called below, Is will be 0 - N
constexpr std::array<int, sizeof...(Is)> make_inc_array_impl(
    std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>) {
  return {{(Is + 1)...}}; // +1 to start at one instead of [0, 1, ...]
}


template <std::size_t N>
constexpr std::array<int, N> make_inc_array() {
  return make_inc_array_impl(std::make_integer_sequence<int, N>{});
}
```

Then call with your size

```
constexpr auto a = make_inc_array<100>(); // [1, 2, ..., 100]
```

This is far less flexible than a list comprehension, and you're probably way better off just using `std::iota` and initializing at runtime.

Answer (score 5):

**C++14** allows loops at compile time.

```
constexpr auto make_upto_100() {
    std::array< int, 100 > ret = {};
    for ( int i = 0; i != 100; ++ i ) ret[i] = i + 1;
    return ret;
}
```

**C++11** allows a utility like `make_index_sequence` which might be more like your thinking. (C++14 also has `std::[make_]index_sequence`.)

```
template< std::size_t ... i >
struct index_sequence
    { typedef index_sequence< i ..., sizeof ... (i) > next; };

template< std::size_t last >
struct index_seq_maker
    { typedef typename index_seq_maker< last - 1 >::type::next type; };

template<>
struct index_seq_maker< 0 >
    { typedef index_sequence<> type; };

template< std::size_t n >
using make_index_sequence = typename index_seq_maker< n >::type;

template< int ... i >
constexpr
std::array< int, 100 >
make_upto_100( index_sequence< i ... > )
    { return {{ i + 1 ... }}; }

constexpr
std::array< int, 100 > upto_100() = make_upto_100( make_index_sequence< 100 >{} );
```

Comment: @RyanHaining Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not compile time, but typically, I'd expect to most code to use [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota). This might actually be faster than compile-time magic in some cases, since compile time arrays would need to be stored in the executable's `.data` segment; if the array is large enough, reading the extra disk pages in from `.data` might end up slower than writing to purely-in-memory pages that are pulled fresh from the OS.

Simple usage would be:

```
int buf[100];
std::iota(&buf[0], &buf[100], 1);
```

Frankly, I'd start here, and only start looking at template magic if you have a proven performance issue with runtime initialization.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for c++14. It works by recursive template instanciation to initialize all the values as a `constexpr`. You should be able to change the size of sequential values to whatever you need by changing the template parameter. Note for very large arrays it could hit the recursion limit:

```
#include <array>

template<int NumVal, int ArrSize>
constexpr void setVal(std::array<int, ArrSize> &constArr) {
        std::get<NumVal>(constArr) = NumVal + 1;
        if(NumVal) setVal<NumVal ? NumVal - 1 : 0, ArrSize>(constArr);
}

template<int ArrSize>
constexpr auto arrRange() -> std::array<int, ArrSize> {
        std::array<int, ArrSize> tmp{};
        setVal<ArrSize - 1, ArrSize>(tmp);
        return tmp;
}

constexpr std::array<int, 100> constArr = arrRange<100>();

int main() {
        for(int itr = 0; itr < 100; ++itr) printf("%d ", constArr[itr]);
}
```